# Cannot fork, even with unlimited ulimit

Tags: operating-system, shell

While executing a shell script in ksh I'm getting the following error:

> myscript.sh[13]: cannot fork - try again

I thought I ran out of processes, but `ulimit -a` returns this:

```
# ulimit -a
time(cpu-seconds)    unlimited
file(blocks)         unlimited
coredump(blocks)     unlimited
data(kbytes)         unlimited
stack(kbytes)        unlimited
lockedmem(kbytes)    unlimited
memory(kbytes)       unlimited
nofiles(descriptors) 1000
processes            unlimited
vmemory(kbytes)      unlimited
```

This is my script, which sends an IPC message to another device through /dev/ipc/ch2:

```
#!/bin/sh

TIMEOUT=40

echo "Petting watchdog for $TIMEOUT seconds..."

c=1
while [[ $c -le $TIMEOUT ]]; do
#   echo "Petting $c"
    sleep 1
    echo -n "\001\002\003\004" > /dev/ipc/ch2
    (( c++ ))
done

echo "Done petting dog..."
```

What could it be?, I don't see why forking gets restricted suddenly.

Comment: Add `echo at c=$c 1>&2` inside the while loop. Does it crash before it gets to that, or after it gets to c=??. Good luck.

Comment: do a `set -x` on the top of the script to watch every command as executed. you could post results if they are helpful

Answer (score 2):

It also says you have unlimited memory.  In reality it's physically limited by the installed RAM plus swap space.  A similar thing happens with processes.  The operating system can only reserve a certain amount of space for a process table.  "Unlimited" doesn't mean you can have a trillion processes, just that the operating system isn't artificially limiting it below the natural amount.

You can write to `/proc/sys/kernel/pid_max` to increase available processes on Linux.  See [here](http://www.cyberciti.biz/tips/howto-linux-increase-pid-limits.html) for more information.

Comment: So is there any way to increase the space for the process table?